# Understanding factorize function

Tags: python, math

Note that this question contains some spoilers.

A [solution for problem #12](http://pyeuler.wikidot.com/problems-11-20) states that

> "Number of divisors (including 1 and the number itself) can be calculated taking one element from prime (and power) divisors."

The (python) code that it has doing this is `num_factors = lambda x: mul((exp+1) for (base, exp) in factorize(x))` (where `mul()` is `reduce(operator.mul, ...)`.)

It doesn't state how `factorize` is defined, and I'm having trouble understanding how it works. How does it tell you the number of factors of the number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The basic idea is that if you have a number factorized into the following form which is the standard form actually:

```
let p be a prime and e be the exponent of the prime:

N = p1^e1 * p2^e2 *....* pk^ek
```

Now, to know how many divisors N has we have to take into consideration every combination of prime factors. So you could possibly say that the number of divisors is:

```
e1 * e2 * e3 *...* ek
```

But you have to notice that if the exponent in the standard form of one of the prime factors is zero, then the result would also be a divisor. This means, we have to add one to each exponent to make sure we included the ith p to the power of zero. Here is an example using the number 12 -- same as the question number :D

```
Let N = 12
Then, the prime factors are:
2^2 * 3^1
The divisors are the multiplicative combinations of these factors. Then, we have:
2^0 * 3^0 = 1
2^1 * 3^0 = 2
2^2 * 3^0 = 4
2^0 * 3^1 = 3
2^1 * 3^1 = 6
2^2 * 3^1 = 12
```

I hope you see now why we add one to the exponent when calculating the divisors.

Comment: Thanks! It makes perfect sense now. Will accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: That is wrong. You have to add one to every exponent first to get the correct result (see my solution).

Comment: @Landei Please read the answer again, I explain why we need to add one actually. "This means, we have to add one to each exponent to make sure we included the ith p to the power of zero"

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Python specialist, but for calculating the number of divisors, you need the prime factorization of the number.

The formula is easy: You add one to the exponent of every prime divisor, and multiply them.

Examples:

12 = 2^2 * 3^1  -> Exponents are 2 and 1, plus one is 3 and 2, 3 * 2 = 6 divisors (1,2,3,4,6,12)

30 = 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^1 -> Exponents are 1, 1 and 1, plus one is 2, 2, and 2, 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 divisors (1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30)

40 = 2^3 * 5^1 -> Exponents are 3 and 1, plus one is 4 and 2, 4 * 2 = 8 divisors (1,2,4,5,8,10,20,40)

Comment: What is the general formula which allows you to determine the exponents?

Comment: You have to factorize the number, AFAIK there is no other way to determine the exponents.