# How do I solve Euler problem 12?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Project Euler Problem 12 - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808148/project-euler-problem-12-c)

I've been working on Euler problems and hit a wall with problem 12. I read up on some mathematical solutions for large numbers but I'm still not getting the right answer. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int divisorCount(const unsigned long long x)
{
    int divizers = 0;
    unsigned long long i = 1;
    while(i <= x/i)
    {
        if(x % i == 0)
        {
            divizers++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return divizers;
}

int main()
{
    bool test;
    unsigned long long total = 0, spread = 1;
    int divisors = 1;

    while(divisors < 501)
    {
        total+=spread;
        divisors = divisorCount(total);
        spread++;
        if(divisors > 501)
            cout << total << " " << spread << " " << divisors << endl;
    }


    cout << total << " is divisible by 500+ numbers" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the task? no link, no text.. :/

Comment: @yi_H - [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=12) is reasonably well known.

Comment: I'm aware of that. It's still advised to link external resources.

Answer (score 1):

there are divisors for x above sqrt(x), so fix this:

```
while(i <= x/i)
```

to:

```
while(i <= x)
```

also, do `spread++;` after the printing so it shows the correct number.

Note: for testing it's good idea to remove the `if` before the printing so you see what's going on.

Note2: a lot quicker way to solve this is to realise the properties of those numbers, see: [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). The Euler project is heavily math based, so don't code brute-force solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Think about your `if` statement:

```
if(x % i == 0)
{
    divizers++;
}
```

Since `i` is a factor of `x`, what other factor of `x` can you immediately write down?  If 3 is a factor of 24, what other factor of 24 do you know?  There is a hidden catch in this hint, just so you are aware.