# finding divisors from sequence of triangle

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Project Euler Problem 12 - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808148/project-euler-problem-12-c)

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. Hence, the 7th
triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28.

The first ten terms would be:

```
1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
```

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

```
1: 1

3: 1,3

6: 1,2,3,6

10: 1,2,5,10

15: 1,3,5,15

21: 1,3,7,21

28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
```

We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors. What is the value of the
first triangle number to have over one hundred divisors?

Comment: Just curious, is that a programming assignment or mathematics homework?

Comment: its a programming assignment..

Comment: havent started yet..i don't know how to begin...

Comment: Search here on SO for Project Euler Problem 12. There are several questions and answers for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You've only copied the problem description!  What's your problem with the problem?  You have to state that.

The question is posed *"what is the 1st triangle number to have over one hundred divisors?"*  Simply iterate over the triangle numbers, finding out how many factors each one has.  When you find one with >100 factors, you're done.

```
for each whole number 'n' from 1 -> +INF
    let tn = triangleNumber(n);
    let nf = numFactors(tn);
    if (nf > 100)
        print tn " has " nf " factors.\n";
        return;
```

Comment: i don't know how to start it yet..i'm not sure to use 'for loop' or 'while..do loop'....

Comment: @MahadevanBlackyD, dirty little secret, doesn't really matter which one you use, I guess for loops are more usual when you know the range you want to iterate over and while when you are more uncertain about the number of iterations needed to reach the end condition. Then there is do..while which is a separate case in iteself. They are all just syntactic sugar for a bunch of conditional jumps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try do it by yourself. If you are not able to get your answer then understand this code.Try to understand the problem and then try to impliment it by yourself. Firstly you have to check untill your divisor is over 100 so there would be one while loop.Inside that while you have to create that sequence of triangle i.e sum of consecutive numbers (1+2+3+4+5+6+7). And then use counter and increment it to find out the number of divisor of the sum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int div=0,sum=0,num,i=1,chk=0,a;
cout<<"enter the number of divisors"<<endl;
cin>>a;
while(div<=a)
{div=0;                                 
sum=sum+i;
for(int j=1;j<=sum;j++)
{if(sum%j==0)
div++;
}
chk++;
i++;
}
cout<<"Value of first triangle number value is "<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"Value of triangle number is "<<chk<<endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```