# I need my program to say "this value is not valid"

Tags: c++

Here's the question to my work.

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. Hence, the 7th triangle number would be `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28`. The first ten terms would be: `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...`

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

```
1: 1

3: 1,3

6: 1,2,3,6

10: 1,2,5,10

15: 1,3,5,15

21: 1,3,7,21

28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
```

We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors. What is the value of the first triangle number to have over one hundred divisors?

and this this is my code. I am having trouble with the error handling.The only valid inputs are numbers. If I enter anything other than a number, i want it to  respond "ERROR" or something like that.

```
int main()
{

    int div=0,sum=0,num,i=1,count=0,a;
    cout<<"Enter the number of divisors"<< endl;
    cin>>a;
    while(div<=a) { 
        div=0;
        sum=sum+i;
        for(int j=1;j<=sum;j++)
            if (sum%j==0)
                div++;
        chk++;
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"Value of first triangle number is "<<sum<<endl;
    cout<<"Value of triangle number is "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

also i did my program before my pseudocode and the flowchart,so if any1 can help me guide through my pseudocode n flowchart,it would be appreciated.thank you. =)

Comment: I notice you have no error handling. How do you detect the error? This needs to be part of the actual logic.

Comment: @arafangion,yes.wic is what i need help for this.how do i do the error handling for this while maintaning my same code.i just want to add it in.

Comment: Side comment: Use bracers even when you dont strictly need them. This is generally a good habit to pickup early.

Comment: You should search through previous questions to see if yours has already been answered. This seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+validate+input In particular, the first item in that list.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252528/finding-divisors-from-sequence-of-triangle and "your" code is an exact copy of Ravi Kumar's answer.

Comment: OMG!! i really dint know..it luks so alike..well,great minds think alike..LOL..bt for me i just hav trouble with this error handling and the pseudocode..

Comment: It doesn't just look alike. Your code is an exact copy of another person's answer but you have introduced a problem by changing the declaration of `chk` to `count` without fixing the `chk++` inside the loop. Did you plagiarize them or was it the other way around?

Comment: NO!!..i sat the whole evening yesterday doing this..it was all trial and error..thn my friend told me there should be error handling..so i tried to do the error handling,but i just cant seem to complete it.this is my 1st assignment for my course.

Comment: And you happened to introduce that `chk++` that doesn't fit with the rest of it? That's an enormous coincidence!

Comment: Not to mention using the same messages (where index or whatever of a triangle number is called its value). Not to mention that `chk/count` variable is unnecessary burden in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check whether the input and conversion succeeded is to check that the stream is still good afterwards:

```
if (std::cin >> a) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

If you want to recover and try again, then you will need to clear the stream's status, and also remove the bad input, before retrying; something like

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(unsigned(-1), '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{

  int div=0,sum=0,num,i=1,count=0,a;    
  for (;;) {
    cout << "Enter the number of divisor: ";
    if (cin >> a) {
        break;
    } else {
      cout << "Error! Please enter a valid integer." << endl;
      cin.clear(); // remove the fail flag
      cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignore the newline
    }
  }

  while(div<=a) { 
    div=0;
    sum=sum+i;
    for(int j=1;j<=sum;j++)
        if (sum%j==0)
            div++;
    chk++;
    i++;
  }
  cout<<"Value of first triangle number is "<<sum<<endl;
  cout<<"Value of triangle number is "<<count<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is ther sumtin to be inserted in the "for (;;)"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int a = 0;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line) && sscanf(line.c_str(), "%d", &a) != 1)
    {
        puts("Error goes here");
    }

    //the rest code goes here ....
```

Comment: The question is a homework question. If I had mixed C++ and C functions like this in any of my assignments, I would have been marked down. Maybe replace the `puts` call with `cerr << "Error goes here\n"; and `sscanf` to a user-defined function that validates a string. Don't get me wrong, it looks like a good answer, but lecturers can be strict :)

Comment: @ChrisParton then try as Mike suggested. rebuilding a sscanf is not a good idea.

Comment: There wouldn't be a way to do it as compactly as your code (and I have nothing against your code, personally). But you could do it in three steps: Get the next token (`getline`), validate the token (loop through the token and check for non-alpha characters), and then convert the token to an integral value (`stringstream`). That said, it's possible the OP is allowed to use C, in which case I'd go with your code as it involves less writing and would be more efficient.

Comment: @ChrisParton I gotta you. My point is that rebuilding a sscanf is a heavy task, taking the sign, hex, oct, and locale info into a consideration, say 0xff12 is a valid input for a integer.

Comment: I won't argue with that haha. It would be bad enough without accounting for different locales.