# pseudocode help for programming work

Tags: c++, pseudocode

How do I write the pseudocode for  highlighted part and the `if....` part?

```
Div=0;

 Sum= sum + number;

 **For (int j=1; j<=sum; j++))**

       If (sum%j==0)

          Div ++;

 Count ++;

 Number ++;
```

Comment: You want someone else to write pseudocode for the [code you plagiarized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306130/i-need-my-program-to-say-this-value-is-not-valid)?

Answer (score 3):

For the for loop, i'd typically write something like

```
for each j from 1 to sum
    if sum is divisible by j
        Div <-- Div + 1
```

Pseudocode is a rather subjective thing, though.  To me, an important property of pseudocode is that it is close to English.  (In particular, the "syntax" is intentionally loose, as it isn't meant to be compiled anyway.  Pseudocode is meant to describe the algorithm to people, not computers.)  I'd consider the `++`s and semicolons kinda counter to the purpose.

Comment: thank u so much for your help.. <3

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this [notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) it would be something like that

```
FOR j = 1 TO sum
  IF sum MOD j = 0
     div = div + 1
 ...
```

Comment: thank u so much for your help.. <3

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
 div=0;
sum= sum + number; //you should determine initial values for sum and number, any set (int, long...)

FOR 1 TO sum
{
    if (sum MOD j == 0) //I think you can use the name of the operation here, to be more clear.
        div = div + 1;
}

count = count + 1;
number = number + 1;
```

That would be clear enough for me!

EDIT

I really think the other suggestions help also, specially the one about being readable for people and not computers.

Comment: thank u so much for your help.. <3