# Getting the first Triangle number with more than 400 divisors

Tags: java, math, for-loop, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Project Euler Problem 12 - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808148/project-euler-problem-12-c)

I am trying to get the first triangle number with more than 400 divisors (Triangle Number eg: 1,3,6,10). For an example, triangle number 6 has four divisors 1,2,3,6. The following is my attempt to get the triangle number with 400 divisors

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class IQ3
{

        static int num1 = 1;    
        static int devideResult = 0;      

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


        while(true)
        {
            int triangle = num1*(num1+1)/2;

            if(devide(triangle))
            {
                break;
            }

            num1++;
        }

    }

    static boolean devide(int num)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        int devideCounter = 2;       


        for(int i=1;i<=num/2;i++)
            {
                if(num%i == 0)
                {
                    devideCounter++;
                    System.out.println("Devide Counter: "+devideCounter);
                    //System.out.println("i number: "+i);
                    //System.out.println("input number: "+num);

                    if(devideCounter>400)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Number: "+num);
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        return result;
    }
}
```

But this takes a huge time, and some times it crashes.

However, since the answer could be really big, I thought of using BigInteger.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class IQ2P2
{

        static BigInteger num1 = new BigInteger("1");
        static BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
        static BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
        static BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1");
        static BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");


        static int devideResult = 0;        
    //    static int devideCounter = 0;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


        while(true)
        {
            BigInteger triangle = num1.multiply(num1.add(one)).divide(two);

            if(devide(triangle))
            {
                break;
            }

            num1.add(one);
        }

    }

    static boolean devide(BigInteger num)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        int devideCounter = 2;       


        while((i.compareTo(num))<(num.divide(two).intValue()))
            {
                if(num.remainder(i) == zero)
                {
                    devideCounter++;
                    System.out.println("Devide Counter: "+devideCounter);
                    //System.out.println("i number: "+i);
                    //System.out.println("input number: "+num);

                    if(devideCounter>400)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Number: "+num);
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i.add(one);
            }

        return result;
    }
}
```

But the biginteger one never returned anything.

Please help me to get first Triangle number with more than 400 divisors.

*Note: This is not a homework. I am not a student.*

The following is a response to an answer

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class IQ2
{

        static long num1 = 1;
        static long numberToAdd = 0;
        static long devideResult = 0;  


       static   long triangleNum = 1;
    static long incrementer = 2;
    //    static int devideCounter = 0;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


        while(true)
        {
            triangleNum += incrementer++;

            if(devide(triangleNum))
            {
                break;
            }

            num1++;
        }

    }

    static boolean devide(long num)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        int devideCounter = 2;       


        for(long i=1;i<=num/2;i++)
            {
                if(num%i == 0)
                {
                    devideCounter++;
                    System.out.println("Devide Counter: "+devideCounter);
                    //System.out.println("i number: "+i);
                    //System.out.println("input number: "+num);

                    if(devideCounter>400)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Number: "+num);
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: My algorithm below can be made a lot more efficient. But if this is a project euler problem it is up to you to find out how.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden:  I am not in project Euler.  I will check your answer

Comment: It is project euler problem 12 (http://projecteuler.net/problem=12). I have retracted my answer (PE problems should not be spoiled).

Comment: You don't need `BigInteger`. The 21735th triangle number is just `236215980` (`< 2^28`), and has `768` divisors.

Comment: I don't know whether this is project Euler or not. Given to me by my friends. Whatever it is, I didn't ask any of you for an 100% answer, because the given code of mine works. I only asked a way to speed it up. If you gave me the complete answer, it is not my fault. If you reject to give answers, I don't mind it. My code worked in another machine.

Comment: Marking this thread as solved

Comment: @Sepala: I did not mean to indicate you knew this was a Project Euler problem. Project Euler specifically asks people not to post solutions to their problems on the internet, which is the reason I retracted my post. What was in there was only part of the solution. It certainly is possible to write code that is much faster.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden: OK. I visited project Euler usng the above link you gave. It seems to be cool anyway. Cooler than CodeCheff I guess. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to optimize the way you find out the amount of divisors for a given number. First, for every `d <= sqrt(n)` such that `n%d==0`, there is `m=n/d` such that `n%m==0` and `m >= sqrt(n)`. That means you can count both of them at once, stopping at `sqrt(n)`.

But the real optimization is to calculate the [prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor) of a number instead, and find out the [amount of divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#number_of_divisors_formula) from there.

Answer (score 1):

As there is not really a rule or pattern to how many divisors the i-th triangle number has, you'll have to start at the beginning and test every number.

So the optimization (in my opinion) can only be performed on the "how many divisors has this number"-question.

You could just only check all prime numbers (with building the set of prime numbers up during checks). This would decrease the time significantly, although I don't know if this is already the fastest solution (I doubt it).

Comment: no, that's not the only optimization. you can also optimize what is meant by "this number".